# onClickListener of Button in custom android dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I Create a dialog in java and show it when a button  was clicked,
in this dialog I have a button , how can I set OnClickListener of this button?
This code show my dialog:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTaskPlus);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
                d.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.task_new_layout);
                d.show();
            }
        });
```

and in task_new_layout.xml i have this button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveTask"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            style="@style/btnSuccess"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_task"
            />
```

I create an onClickListener for this button but it wont work and has no error!!

```
final View taskView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_new_layout, container, false);
        Button btnSaveTask = (Button) taskView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTask);
        btnSaveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("MGH","clicked");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Dialog.findViewById();` instead of inflating the view and finding your button again.

try this in your `ImageView` click listner

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
    d.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.task_new_layout);
    Button btnSaveTask = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTask);
    btnSaveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("MGH", "clicked");
        }
    });
    d.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-inflating your view, which creates a new instance of the `Button` and this new instance is not loaded anywhere. `Button` on `Dialog` is a different instance and on that you don't have any `OnClickListener` attached.

When you press the `Button` on `Dialog` your code do not get executed.

Do this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
    d.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.task_new_layout);
    Button myBtn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTask);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // your code
        }
    });
    d.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try  setContentView(taskview)

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTaskPlus);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
                d.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                d.setContentView(taskView);
                d.show();
            }
        });


final View taskView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_new_layout, container, false);
        Button btnSaveTask = (Button) taskView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTask);
        btnSaveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("MGH","clicked");
            }
        });
```